# Swift SubView Positioning to StoryBoard Item

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, frame, viewcontroller

I have a View Controller with a NavBar Item added through the storyboard interface. However, I made a Collection View programmatically and would like it to be positioned on the y-axis so it always right underneath the NavBar for any screen size. I don't know how to go about this but the code below is how its placed in the view Controller right now.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 65).integral
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collectionView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: NavBar.frame.maxY , width: view.frame.size.width, height: 65).integral
```

Answer (score 2):

If you embed the view controller inside a `NavigationController` and then add the `UICollectionView` in code, setting its anchors to the safe area (or at least the top one) will achieve what you are asking, it will even sync the collection view's scrolling with a pull on the navbar if you are putting any large titles in it.

Also, I wouldn't set the frame of the collection view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, just set its anchors after having added it to its parent view.

Maybe something like:

```swift
view.addSubview(collectionView)
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let safeArea = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
[ 
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor, constant: 0),
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
].forEach { $0.isActive = true }
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```